# In-App receipt validation within app itself

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

For auto-renewable subscriptions, I want to implement the "transactionReceipt" validation within the app itself, by building json object, parsing the data received and checking status value.

I want to know if there is any disadvantage by implementing this type of approach, rather than validating receipt on the server.

Mohan.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this in app for next reasons:

1. You can restore all purchases using `StoreKit`.
2. Hacker can set proxy and return to your app any answers that you will think APNS has returned to you.

When you are validating receipt on the server hacker couldn't simulate answers from APNS.

Hope, I'm clear.